# How can I convert sql to linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-to-linq-conversion

This is my SQL query

```
SELECT 
sys.sysobjects.name Name,
sys.foreign_keys.*
FROM 
sys.foreign_keys 
inner join sys.sysobjects on
    sys.foreign_keys.parent_object_id = sys.sysobjects.id
WHERE 
referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Country]')
```

I have installed Linqer to convert SQL to linq.
But I got an error:

> SQL cannot be converted to LINQ: Table [foreign_keys] not found in the current Data Context.

I am a beginner in Linq. Can Anyone help me to convert SQL to Linq

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339732/convert-sql-to-linq-to-sql
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238423/linqpad-convert-sql-to-linq-command

Comment: imonas:I alrweady have Linqer and linqpad.But am getting error 'SQL cannot be converted to LINQ: Table [foreign_keys] not found in the current Data Context.'

Comment: The problem is that system views will not be picked up by Linqer. If you want to read these tables in your application, first create your own views on them, as was done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8099311/861716) and write a query on these views.

Comment: @GertArnold :-Can u please give me little more explanation...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that system views will not be picked up by Linqer. If you want to read these tables in your application, first create your own views on them, as was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8099311/861716) and write a query on these views.

```sql
CREATE VIEW SysObjectsView AS SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects;
GO
CREATE VIEW SysForeignKeysView AS SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys;
GO

SELECT obj.name Name, fk.*
FROM SysForeignKeysView fk
INNER JOIN SysObjectsView obj ON fk.parent_object_id = obj.id
INNER JOIN SysObjectsView objfk ON fk.referenced_object_id = objfk.id
WHERE objfk.name = N'Country'
```

Linqer should be able to pick up these views.

Comment: Is it possible to get related table names using linq in mvc3.The code i posted works well,but wat chnges i have to make to work it in mvc3

Comment: Make the views part of the linq-to-sql context.

Comment: got an error when i post your code in Linqer "Error Compiling Expression: Too many characters in character literal
"